# Definition of the tipping point

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have seen this mentioned in papers (e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.4290.pdf)). I have a vague idea that a tipping point of a dynamical system is the state where small fluctuations can cause major changes in behavior.
Is there a rigorous (or at least clearer) definition of what a tipping point means in math?

Comment: Mind that the quality of that journal is debatable. I suggest to read their [foreword](http://www.ijtst.com/foreword.asp) and form your own opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no consensus on defining *tipping points,* but in many contexts that concern dynamical systems, it is usually some kind of [bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory).
A bifurcation is a sudden change of the dynamics of a dynamical system when a parameter is infinitesimally changed.

There are some kinds of bifurcations that I would not expect to be referred to as tipping points, namely those which do not lead to a first-order discontinuity in phase space.
By *first-order discontinuity,* I mean that reasonable observables of the dynamics are discontinuous with respect to a parameter (a jump in the bifurcation diagram), as opposed to their derivative being discontinuous (a kink in the bifurcation diagram).
This equivalent to the union of attractors undergoing a discontinuous change.
For example, period doublings are only second-order discontinuous and thus usually not considered tipping points.

Often tipping points are considered to happen in a noise-free version of the actual dynamics or a comparable simplification.
A typical example for this is when the tipping point makes the system bistable, and the other attractor becomes relevant as it can be reached through noise.